# Como compilar en sublime text 3 usando FPC 3.0 LINUX (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3, pascal, freepascal

Me interesa saber el código al crear una nueva build system, para compilar en con Free Pascal usando linux, o en simples palabras cómo configurar Sublime Text para compilar archivos `.pas` en linux.

Comment: No me queda claro si es lo que necesitas pero el comando para compilar pascal desde la terminal es fpc -Co -Cr -gl -Mtp nombre_del_archivo.pas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comando para compilar pascal desde la terminal utilizando el *ide freepascal* es (invocamos el compilador):

```
$ fpc -Co -Cr -Mtp -gl hola.pas
```

Se impone analizar este comando palabra por palabra:

`fpc`: Es el nombre del compilador *Free Pascal*.

`hola.pas`: Es el nombre del archivo que contiene el programa fuente.

`-Co` y `-Cr`: Son opciones que le indican al compilador que debe generar el control de rangos y desborde de operaciones aritméticas.

`-gl`: Hace que el compilador en caso de error en tiempo de ejecución, indique la línea del código fuente donde se produce dicho error.

`-Mtp`: Es una opción que hace que el compilador se aproxime más al Pascal estándar.

Fuente: Instituto de computación (Facultad de ingeniería UDELAR).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, me has ayudado un montón. :D